# Exporting to SVG in fabric with svgs doesn't match canvas

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, fabricjs

We are using Fabric.js 1.7.20. We aren't able (yet) to update to 2.0+.

http://jsfiddle.net/tcem4f4L/

The issue is that we are adding SVG objects to the map, but when they get output to an svg, some padding within the SVG causes the rendering to not look correct. The svg x/y coordinates and any lines within them need to have the stroke accounted for.

I'm trying to figure out a clean way to handle these and ensure that the bounding box on the canvas is around the SVG for aligning purposes.

Example SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="95" height="11" viewBox="0 0 95 11" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="95" height="11"></rect>
    <path stroke-linecap="square" stroke-width="3" d="M1,9 l93,0"/>
  </g>  
</svg>
```

So (I think) to fix it on output to SVG, I'd need to change the rect x and y to 0.5 and the path to d="M1.5,9.5 l93,0"

I am worried that there are other things in this I'm missing.